# Asking for a short sentence, how many to appear, and print it out

Tags: python

I'm working on commands by telling them making a short sentence, asking how many to appear and prints it out that goes like this:

```
a=eval(input("Type something in short: "))
b=eval(input("How many?: "))
for b in a:
    for a in range(b):
        print(a)
```

I need to ask people, Is there an error on a code on python?

Comment: can you define `sen`

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice. sorry about that.

Comment: You have logical error. Are you expecting it to count occurrence of `b` in `a`?

Comment: could you provide example input and output?

Comment: The input goes as follows: 'Type something in short: Hi there' and asking me for how many to appear which I'll say 6 times. The output should look like this when it says Hi there 6 times

Comment: Never use eval() on user input, it allows people to input whatever code they like, and eval() will execute ir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing your objective is to print `a` `b` number of times.

For that, you don't need to even use a loop. Just do :

```
print(a*int(b))

In : Type something in short : "abc"
In : How many?: "3"
Out : abcabcabc
```

Now, incase you wanted the string in new line, just add `\n` to the string.

```
print((a+'\n')*int(b))

In : Type something in short : "abc"
In : How many?: "3"
Out : abc
      abc
      abc
```

As for the  error in your code, you have used an extra `for` loop and have a few mistakes. It should be :

```
for i in range(b):
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print it for `b` times you can just use one `for` loop:

```
for i in range(b):
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Few different ways to do this :

#assuming `a: str` and `b: int`

---

**String multiply :**

```
print((a+'\n')*b)
```

---

***Round about* way by using list and join :**

```
l = [a]*b
print('\n'.join(l))
```

---

**Simple for loop :**

```
for i in range(b):
    print(a)
```